# Fantasy manhwa where the female lead is actually a devil but also has a human form

Tags: story-identification, manga, demons

I can’t really remember much but what I can remember is that the female lead was reincarnated (or just wakes up) as a human. She’s also the Devil’s daughter in a different dimension. She can also teleport between them and changes how she looks. She’s also on a mission that her father gave her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? And what was the mission that her father gave her?

Comment: Just to confirm - the FL was not a demon that was summoned by a human for revenge and took over her body (hence having a human and demon form). Correct?

Comment: qazmlpok i think you just made me remember i probably mixed different plots

Comment: Just to confirm before I write up an answer; human summons a demon (the FL) for revenge against the queen for poisoning her. Demon accepts, but is basically stuck in her body now. She can return to the demon world, but not as her original form. She trains with a bunch of soliders, and I think gets them to win a tournament (embarrassing the queen, iirc). Sound like the story you're thinking of?

Comment: EXACTLY OMG i think u got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Demonic Contract](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-demonic-contract)*. It is available on [Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/the-demonic-contract).

> Yurisina, **the daughter of the demon king**, has always wanted to become a full-fledged demon by making her first contract with a human. That's when Princess Marianne of the Pedin Kingdom summoned her to take revenge on Queen Orphelius who poisoned her, and asks Yurisina to live in her place...

The story opens with Yurisina, a demon, accepting a contract with Princess Marianne. This results in her getting stuck in the human's body as part of the terms of the contract. She's not able to change her appearance after this, but does change in the first chapter:

[image: Demon and princess]

She is still able to return to the demon world and does so during chapters 11 and 12. She discovers that her human body is unable to use her demonic magic and strength, and seeks assistance from her family.

[image: Demons eagerly greeting]

Comment: i can finally read it . this manhwa has been in my mind for months and i couldn’t find it tysmmmm

Comment: @noor You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).